# Cisco IOS command : default-information originate vs redistribute static

Tags: cisco, ospf, rip, eigrp

I am quite confusing with the Cisco IOS command.

what's the actual difference between redistribute static as i learn in EIGRP whereas default-information originate in RIP/RIPv2/OSPF?

I hope to get some answer over here as i can't find the difference from google neither cisco website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`default-information originate` injects a default route (ie 0.0.0.0/0) in the routing table of the peers, while `redistribute static` will redistribute static routes (`ip route xxx`) into the routing protocol.